# Zero Copy byte[] or ByteBuffer with HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, zero-copy, flatbuffers

When using Google's FlatBuffer, the type that ends up being used is a `ByteBuffer` (which can just wrap a `byte[]`).  I am using this with an `HttpServletResponse`.  The problem becomes the Servlets `PrintWriter` does not offer `byte[]` or `ByteBuffer` writing.

Any tips in being able to output from an `HttpServletResponse` without having to copy the `ByteBuffer`/`byte[]` into another type?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the question as I have found the answer in this PDF question: [How to send byte[] as pdf to browser in java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592058/how-to-send-byte-as-pdf-to-browser-in-java-web-application)

It turns out the servlet has an `getOutputStream` method which offers a `byte[]` write method.